# Calculating midpoints

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I've been unable to wrap my head around the use of `(low + high)/2` for calculating the midpoint of an array in binary search and other algorithms that use a similar operation. In my opinion it should be something like `low + (high-low+1)/2`.

How do we arrive at former from the latter ?

Please excuse if this is too naive. A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, `low + (high-low+1)/2` == `(2*low)/2 + (high-low+1)/2` == `(2*low + high-low+1)/2` == `(high+low+1)/2`, so you're only off by a half...

Comment: the half would be significant if `high + low` is a odd. It makes sense if I examine it empirically, but how do I deduce it ?

Comment: I think the only difference is, when the array length is even (i.e. `high+low` is odd), yours chooses the element closer to the end, while `(low+high)/2` chooses the element closer to the beginning.

Comment: when the middle does not exist (even total size say 8) then you need to choose either the fourth or fifth element to represent the middle,
this choice is done by the programmer and you just have to be consistent when checking end points that's all